# Audit Queries in SQL Server 2008 Including Start Stop Times

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, audit

I have SQL Server 2008 Enterprise. I know how to set up auditing on the SQL Server, but it looks like the audit logs don't include query start/stop times.

We currently use a product called Splunk to do a lot of data analysis at our organization. I would like to be able to feed Splunk our machine performance data along with a SQL query audit log to be able to correlate high CPU usage to long running queries and things like that.

However, I would need query start/stop times to be able to do that. It doesn't look like the built in auditing has that ability. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Edit:
I am aware of the event time column in the audit log. That gets me half way there as it is the start time. So, I either need the query length or the end time to get the data I need.

Comment: The `event_time` column in `sys.fn_get_audit_file` will help. `SELECT event_time, database_name, schema_name, object_name, statement
 FROM sys.fn_get_audit_file('C:\SqlAudits\*.sqlaudit', default, default)` Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280765.aspx

Comment: That gets me half way there. That is the start time, but I need the end time as well. Maybe I should have said in my description that I mostly need the end time.

Comment: Auditing really isn't meant to do that. You'll probably have to run a trace or extended events session to capture that information. You should be able to use those to correlate against the PerfMon data.

Comment: @DavinStuder agreed with Jon that you have to use profiler to get the start and end time of the queries. Audit wont give you that flexiblity - its by design. As a side note, you can have a server side trace running (remember that capturing all the queries will have a performance impact on the server) and then a procedure that will import the trace data in a sql server table and then you can do your analysis .

Comment: I've never used server side tracing ... I understand the concept just never done it. Is it ok to have a server side trace running all the time ... will this kill my db performance?

Comment: Extended events have lower overhead than server-side traces, so start there.

Comment: Thanks for the advice with extended events ... never even heard about them till now.  Cool Stuff.